# Determine the Linear Transformation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a problem below here:

The Matrix R is below:

\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

And i have a Linear Transformation below here below that defines
by this below.

The linear Transformation $S: \mathbb R^3 \to  \mathbb R^3$ is given by $S (x) = R (x) + 3x.$

My problem here is that i don't understand how to get the Matrix $S$ from the definition
above.

Should I insert the standard matrix and try it like $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ because I have know idea to get the matrix $S$???

Comment: Notice that $S = R + 3I_{3}$, where $I_{3}$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia Thanks How do you know that it is S = R +3*I should be applied?

Comment: That's because

$$Rx + 3x = Rx + 3I_{3}x = (R + 3I_{3})x$$

where I have applied the distributive property of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Try using MathJax formatting for future questions and answers. It makes your questions look better and it's easier to write them. See a tutorial on MathJax here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Lukas Where can i find MathJax?

Comment: You just type it in when you write a question or an answer - it is already implemented here in stackexchange. For example, to write an equation you start with a \$-sign and end with a \$-sign